# What does "inflate" mean here?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I'm installing Oracle database and below is an excerpt of the installation log. What does *inflating* mean here? I know the installer was copying these files to the destination when these lines were being printed. So does *inflating* is a humorous way of saying *copying*? Like inflating a dinghy is essentially doing some preparation work, just like copying files. Is my understanding correct?

[image]

Comment: Like unzipping or decompressing?

Comment: The files were compressed and the copying process de-compressed them as they were copied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine your files are balloons. When the balloons are not inflated (compressed) they are smaller and easier to handle. You are inflating (decompressing) the 'balloons'.